# Search input as option in Material UI Select component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I need to make Select component with Search input as first option in dropdown list. Something like this:
[image]

The main problem is that Search component acts as normal  from  input. I don't know how to make it focusable. Thank you.

Comment: You should add a code example of what you tried and a link to a codesandbox.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the reason for placing the search input in dropdown list? i.e do you want to search in dropdown list items?

Answer (score 47):

### Problem Explanation

This happens because `MenuItem` is a direct child of the `Select` component. It acts in the same way as described in [Selected menu](https://mui.com/components/menus/#selected-menu) documentation. You can see that when `Menu` (or in our case `Select`) is opened, focus is automatically put onto the selected `MenuItem`. That's why `TextField` loses focus in the first place (even if we attach an `autoFocus` attribute to it).

Ok, so we can obviously simply hack this using the `useRef` hook on a `TextField` and then call the `focus()` method when `Select` opens. Something like this:

```
var inputRef = useRef(undefined);
...
<Select onAnimationEnd={() -> inputRef.current.focus()} ... >
    ...
    <TextField ref={inputRef} ... />
    ...
</Select>
```

**Well not so fast, there's a catch!**

Here's where things break: You open your select and focus shifts to the input field as expected. Then you insert search text that would filter out the currently selected value. Now if you remove text with backspace until the currently selected item appears again, you would see that focus would automatically be placed from input field to the currently selected option. It might seem like a viable solution at first but you can see where UX suffers and we don't get expected stable behavior that we want.

### Solution

I find your question a bit vague without any code and proper explanation, but I still find it useful since I was searching for the exact same solution as you: **Searchable Select MUI Component** with good UX. So please note that this is my assumption of what you wanted as a working solution.

Here's a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-searchable-select-nm3vw?file=/src/App.js) with my **working solution**. All the important bits are explained in code comments and here:

- The most important change is adding `MenuProps={{ autoFocus: false }}` attribute to the `Select` component and `autoFocus` attribute to the `TextField` component.
- I've put the search `TextField` into a `ListSubheader` so that it doesn't act as a selectable item in the menu. i.e. we can click the search input without triggering any selection.
- I've added a custom `renderValue` function. This prevents rendering empty string in Select's value field if search text would exclude the currently selected option.
- I've disabled event propagation on `TextField` with the `onKeyDown` function. This prevents auto selecting item while typing (which is default `Select` behavior)
- [BONUS] You can easily extend this component with multi selection support, which was what I ended up making for my project, but I'll not include the details here since it's out of the scope of your question.

Comment: Extremely good answer!

Comment: If I could vote it 100 times I would. Thank you so much.

Comment: omg! MenuProps={{ autoFocus: false }} - 2 hours I was thinking about where to turn this autoselect off! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 11):

The MUI Autocomplete component might be just what you need
[https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/](MUI Autocomplete)

Auto Complete is a Component provided by the MUI Library. It has the same functionality like Select option, and in addition provides a search-option, along with other options improving developer experience. Here is a little snippet of the Autocomplete Component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { label: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { label: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
  { label: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
  { label: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 },
  { label: '12 Angry Men', year: 1957 },
  { label: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { label: 'Pulp Fiction', year: 1994 },
  {
    label: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King',
    year: 2003,
  },
  { label: 'The Good, the Bad and the Ugly', year: 1966 },
  { label: 'Fight Club', year: 1999 },
  {
    label: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring',
    year: 2001,
  },
  {
    label: 'Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back',
    year: 1980,
  },
  { label: 'Forrest Gump', year: 1994 },
  { label: 'Inception', year: 2010 },
  {
    label: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers',
    year: 2002,
  },
  { label: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", year: 1975 },
  { label: 'Goodfellas', year: 1990 },
  { label: 'The Matrix', year: 1999 },
  { label: 'Seven Samurai', year: 1954 },
  {
    label: 'Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope',
    year: 1977,
  },
  { label: 'City of God', year: 2002 },
  { label: 'Se7en', year: 1995 },
  { label: 'The Silence of the Lambs', year: 1991 },
  { label: "It's a Wonderful Life", year: 1946 },
  { label: 'Life Is Beautiful', year: 1997 },
  { label: 'The Usual Suspects', year: 1995 },
  { label: 'Léon: The Professional', year: 1994 },
  { label: 'Spirited Away', year: 2001 },
  { label: 'Saving Private Ryan', year: 1998 },
  { label: 'Once Upon a Time in the West', year: 1968 },
  { label: 'American History X', year: 1998 },
  { label: 'Interstellar', year: 2014 },
  { label: 'Casablanca', year: 1942 },
  { label: 'City Lights', year: 1931 },
  { label: 'Psycho', year: 1960 },
  { label: 'The Green Mile', year: 1999 },
  { label: 'The Intouchables', year: 2011 },
  { label: 'Modern Times', year: 1936 },
  { label: 'Raiders of the Lost Ark', year: 1981 },
  { label: 'Rear Window', year: 1954 },
  { label: 'The Pianist', year: 2002 },
  { label: 'The Departed', year: 2006 },
  { label: 'Terminator 2: Judgment Day', year: 1991 },
  { label: 'Back to the Future', year: 1985 },
  { label: 'Whiplash', year: 2014 },
  { label: 'Gladiator', year: 2000 },
  { label: 'Memento', year: 2000 },
  { label: 'The Prestige', year: 2006 },
  { label: 'The Lion King', year: 1994 },
  { label: 'Apocalypse Now', year: 1979 },
  { label: 'Alien', year: 1979 },
  { label: 'Sunset Boulevard', year: 1950 },
  {
    label: 'Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb',
    year: 1964,
  },
  { label: 'The Great Dictator', year: 1940 },
  { label: 'Cinema Paradiso', year: 1988 },
  { label: 'The Lives of Others', year: 2006 },
  { label: 'Grave of the Fireflies', year: 1988 },
  { label: 'Paths of Glory', year: 1957 },
  { label: 'Django Unchained', year: 2012 },
  { label: 'The Shining', year: 1980 },
  { label: 'WALL·E', year: 2008 },
  { label: 'American Beauty', year: 1999 },
  { label: 'The Dark Knight Rises', year: 2012 },
  { label: 'Princess Mononoke', year: 1997 },
  { label: 'Aliens', year: 1986 },
  { label: 'Oldboy', year: 2003 },
  { label: 'Once Upon a Time in America', year: 1984 },
  { label: 'Witness for the Prosecution', year: 1957 },
  { label: 'Das Boot', year: 1981 },
  { label: 'Citizen Kane', year: 1941 },
  { label: 'North by Northwest', year: 1959 },
  { label: 'Vertigo', year: 1958 },
  {
    label: 'Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi',
    year: 1983,
  },
  { label: 'Reservoir Dogs', year: 1992 },
  { label: 'Braveheart', year: 1995 },
  { label: 'M', year: 1931 },
  { label: 'Requiem for a Dream', year: 2000 },
  { label: 'Amélie', year: 2001 },
  { label: 'A Clockwork Orange', year: 1971 },
  { label: 'Like Stars on Earth', year: 2007 },
  { label: 'Taxi Driver', year: 1976 },
  { label: 'Lawrence of Arabia', year: 1962 },
  { label: 'Double Indemnity', year: 1944 },
  {
    label: 'Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind',
    year: 2004,
  },
  { label: 'Amadeus', year: 1984 },
  { label: 'To Kill a Mockingbird', year: 1962 },
  { label: 'Toy Story 3', year: 2010 },
  { label: 'Logan', year: 2017 },
  { label: 'Full Metal Jacket', year: 1987 },
  { label: 'Dangal', year: 2016 },
  { label: 'The Sting', year: 1973 },
  { label: '2001: A Space Odyssey', year: 1968 },
  { label: "Singin' in the Rain", year: 1952 },
  { label: 'Toy Story', year: 1995 },
  { label: 'Bicycle Thieves', year: 1948 },
  { label: 'The Kid', year: 1921 },
  { label: 'Inglourious Basterds', year: 2009 },
  { label: 'Snatch', year: 2000 },
  { label: '3 Idiots', year: 2009 },
  { label: 'Monty Python and the Holy Grail', year: 1975 },
];
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).